# GUI issue in java

Tags: java, swing

I've made a Menu bar and when i click on Help>>about a popup window jumps.
i also put on the popup window a button and i'm wondering what's the command i should use to close the popup window in the button action listener but not abort the program.
(i tried before to use (System.exit(0)) but it's abort the program.

[image: here's a picture of the button i'm talking about]

Comment: Don't post a picture of your IDE, that doesn't help. In the future post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: In the actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) method, you can use window.dispose(); or setVisible(false); window.dispose();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> i'm wondering what's the command i should use to close the popup window

You would use:

```
window.dispose();
```

Or better yet just use a `JOptionPane` to display the "About" dialog. The `JOptionPane` will build the dialog and buttons for you.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and examples.